# Eliminating outliers / best fit for "spiky" data in Python

Tags: python-2.7, curve-fitting, analysis, outliers

Fairly new to processing data like this; I have two curves that I'm not sure how to process, but I know what I'd like to have as an outcome. The original plots of two datasets are shown below (left); the rough fit that I think I would like to have for them is shown to below (right) with the overlayed fit in red.

First example:
[image]
The sudden drops in amplitude are an artifact on how the data was taken. This means it's inherently unpredictable, and I would ideally like to find a method that is robust to this behavior.

In the first case, I could try to eliminate the sharp drops in amplitude by using a threshold, but that would not help me in the second case:
[image], 
where I still get strong oscillation, but the minima are no longer at 0.

**Edit:** After writing a short script to use @JamesPhillips suggestion, fitting results are shown below; can confirm this is what I was looking for, and works better/faster than other fitting algorithms.

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible algothm: filter the data something like this...

Start with the smallest X-valued point shown on the graph, iterating from smallest X value to largest X value.  For each point:

1) If the next point's Y value is greater than or equal to this point's Y value, include it.

2) If the next point's value is less that [cutoff] percent of this point's Y value, exclude it.

3) Go to next point.

Run the filter and test different values for [cutoff], each time graphing the result to see if the value of [cutoff] meets your requirements.  You may need an additional filter condition or two, but that should be a good start to filtering the data as you describe.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion -- this did exactly what I was looking for, and faster/easier to implement than other fitting kits.  I updated my initial question with results.